# ionic CORS with Ajax call by third party library

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, wkwebview

When making Ajax call by third party library (plain js library, Oracle MCS),
CORS errors shown.
`Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://x.mobile.ocp.oraclecloud.com/mobile/platform/users/login due to access control checks`

From my understanding, the webview engine thinks I'm browsing localhost for ionic pages,
ajax to else where is forbidden.

This is a common issue.
Below is the methods tried:

1. Add index content policy header
   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
   'unsafe-eval'">`
2. Whitelist localhost and remote address
   `<allow-navigation href="https://x.mobile.ocp.oraclecloud.com:443" />`
   `<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080" />`

Workaround:
1. use `UIWebview`
not ok as it is deprecated
2. use `cordova-plugin-advanced-http`
not applicable as the call is made by third party
3. use ionic local proxy in `ionic.config.json` to redirect 
not applicable as the call is made by third party thus cannot modify the call

Sample test case:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://x.mobile.ocp.oraclecloud.com/mobile/platform/users/login");
        xhr.send();
```

Hope to see advise on making Ajax call using native Ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use native http :

install plugin(ionic3) :

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/http@4
```

use post method [ref](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/#post)

Alternative [link](https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend#readme). it seem perfect because it will work in browser(use angular client) and in device use native http.